# Ajax form submission loading result page in another div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am attempting to send data from a form to another page(on the same server) and have that page load within a div on the main index page.  When I submit the data it is being processed but the div is not updating to reflect a new page has been loaded in it.

```
form-page.php

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
  $('#review-submit-button').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pages/firstdeploy/deploy-sequence-finalize1.php',
    data: $("#masteraccountsetup").serialize(),
    success: function(response){
$("#primary-display").html(response);
}

    });
  });
});//end document ready
</script>
```

processing-form-page.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
if (!$con){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error());
};


// escape variables for security
$companyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['review-
companyname']);
$jobtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['review-jobtitle']);
$masteraccount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['review-username']);
$masteremail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['review-email']);
$masterpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['review-
masterpassword']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, company, position, email) 
VALUES ('$masteraccount','$masterpassword',
'$companyname','$jobtitle','$masteremail')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo $companyname;
echo "<br>";
echo $masteraccount;
echo "<br>";
echo $jobtitle;
echo "<br>";
echo $masteremail;
echo "<br> test";
echo $masterpassword;



$con->close();
```

?>

Now the processing page works when I independantly go to it and it also works when submitted through the form page.  The issue is, that it is not updating in to #primary-display from the index page.  The form-page.php is loaded into the #primary-display div at the start of the form sequence.

edit: added index page

```
<div id="primary-holder" class="prima-hold">
<div id="primary-display">
<?php 

// Start the Session
session_start();


 $con=mysqli_connect();
 if (!$con){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error());
 };


  $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);    

  if($count > 0){

   //Display if there is already a restaurant placed in the system
 echo "



  <script>

  $(\"#primary-display\").load(\"pages/security/mainentrance.php\");      

  </script>

  ";
  }else{
   // Display if no restaurants have been placed in the system

  echo "



  <script>

  $(\"#primary-display\").load(\"pages/firstdeploy/intro.php\");      

  </script>

   ";

   };

    ?>

    </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: Just to confirm.  Have you put a console.log(response) in the success method and seen that print to your console?  Verifying that 1) the ajax happens, 2) it got a successful response, 3) the response is what you expect it is

Comment: Also watching the network tab to see what is requested and received? This code looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: I have not, let me see if I can google how to add one.  The reason I know it is processing through the processing-form-page.php is the database table is updated with the results.

Comment: Literally, inside your success method put `console.log(response);`

Comment: You mention you are loading `form-page.php` into that div from `index.php`? Does that `script` block you show, part of `form-page.php` or part of `index.php` ? And could you show us the html where the div with id `primary-display` is.

Comment: I updated the above post with the index page.  The sequence when you load on the page is index.php with the div #primary-display.  Then the form-page.php is loaded into #primary-display.   After filling out the form and submitting I want the processing-form-page.php loaded into #primary-display replacing form-page.php.  Now the form is being processed and results added to the db but its not replacing form-page.php with processing-form-page.php.  I have tried using body instead of #primary-display with no change in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pages/firstdeploy/deploy-sequence-finalize1.php',
    data: $("#masteraccountsetup").serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response){
        $("#primary-display").html(response);
    }
```

If ajax dataType is set as text or html, no pre-processing occurs. The data is simply passed on to the success handler, and made available through the responseText property of the jqXHR object.

from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: this answer does does not work and it no longer loads results into the database

Comment: I dont know how that could stop loading results into the database, as the only thing changed in his example, is `dataType` which ONLY affects what it does with 'returned data'. Has no bearing on the ajax call and serialize and data sent. Which leads me to believe this is not working at all, nor even hitting deploy-sequence-finalize1.php to begin with. Which is a much bigger deep seated issue.

Comment: ok, so, using the code you had posted as is did not work, but adding dataType: 'html', to my existing ajax did solve my problem.  Thank you very much for adding the clarification to your code snippit!

Comment: actually, so rereading a few times what you posted and reading the ajax api I am left with the question, would the form data still be serialized because no preprocessing occurs?

Comment: No processing is applied to the result data and not the form data.

Comment: So, the data sent via ajax to the form processing page will be serialized?